# How can I get the port number of the newly accepted connection in python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

When I create a socket on a server and the accept an incoming connection:

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

Both print `conn.getsockname()` and `print s.getsockname()` print out the same port number.

I thought 'conn' was supposed to represent a NEW socket. How do I get the port number of this new socket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local port remains the same. What you want is the remote side's port. You can use `getpeername` for this (or the second element of `accept`'s return value).

Comment: Thanks. If the local port stays the same, how does the server distinguish between data flows from different clients?

Comment: By the combination of the source and target interfaces and ports.

Comment: Right, sockets are *pairs* of `(host, port)` tuples. Each *pair* is unique. (+1 for good question.)

Comment: It should be a way to get this info directly, without having to save this data previously

Answer (score 0):

It is a new socket, but it has the same local port as the original listening socket.